# Send to Trash with JXA on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, javascript-automation

So I have been looking for an answer to this and have had no luck. Is it possible to send a file to the trash using JXA in Mac Automation? my simple test code looks like this:

```
// set startup applications that this script will use
var app = Application.currentApplication()
var finder = Application("Finder");
app.includeStandardAdditions = true 


function openDocuments(droppedItems)
{
    // Variables
    var AllFiles = [] // array to store all files in.

    for (var item of droppedItems)
    {
        AllFiles.push(item) // load each file into array
    }

    // go through each file in the list
    for (var i = 0; i < AllFiles.length; i ++)
    {
        // move to the trash
        finder.move(Path(AllFiles[i]), {
                to: Path("/Users/usr/.trash"),
                replacing: true
            })
    }
}
```

this is just a test I am building that should send whatever file I drop onto it to the trash, but it does not recognize .trash as a valid folder location. I have tested it with other folder and that does work so I am assuming that .trash is locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a reference to the trash folder via **pathTo** command of *Standard Additions*

For example, to send the currently selected file in the Finder to the Trash, something like this could work.

```
(() => {
    const
        ca = Application.currentApplication(),
        sa = (ca.includeStandardAdditions = true, ca),
        app = Application('Finder'),
        seln = app.selection();

        app.delete(seln[0])
})();
```

Comment: So I tried this, but I get an error that "Can't convert types". I also tried it with .trash in case its because its a hidden folder. the pathTo might be the answer. I will see if I can get it to return a proper file path.